# I am trying to cherry-pick a commit but I get an error

Tags: git, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

**I am trying to cherry-pick a commit but I get an error:**

```
Packaging has failed due to cherry-picking (rebase) failure

Caused by: Commit refs/changes/26/1452826/9 cherry-picking failed due to
failing file(s): {build/folder_name/file_name.py=DIRTY_WORKTREE}
```

Comment: Do you use a custom githooks that packages the app on each commit? Please check the `.git/hooks` directory.

Comment: Sorry for late but I am not using any custom githooks, still getting this error